# Is there any amount limitation for label.new?

Tags: label, pine-script

I have written 300 lines pine scripts witch only contains label.new function, but only part of it works.I can only find the last dozens result show in the chart.

So I want know is there any amount limitation for label.new?

Below is part of my code：

```
label.new(1619163994000, 47909, text='', style=label.style_circle, xloc=xloc.bar_time, color=#b2d235, size=size.tiny)
label.new(1619164295000, 47666, text='', style=label.style_circle, xloc=xloc.bar_time, color=#b2d235, size=size.tiny)
label.new(1619172557000, 49052, text='', style=label.style_circle, xloc=xloc.bar_time, color=#f15b6c, size=size.tiny)
label.new(1619172562000, 49075, text='', style=label.style_circle, xloc=xloc.bar_time, color=#f15b6c, size=size.tiny)
```

Answer (score 0):

I read about these limits just today.  Maybe this is contributing: https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-many-plots-security-calls-variables-or-lines-of-code-can-i-use

Answer (score 0):

From the function `study()` documentation:

> **max_labels_count** (const integer) The number of last label drawings displayed. The default value is 50 and the maximum allowed is 500.